# Encrypting a part of the data using AES256

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am working with unstructured data and I want to encrypt only specific fields of the data that relate to customer PII. Is it possible to encrypt only the PII data using AES256?

Comment: You can encrypt as little or as much as you want.

Comment: Possible is everything, but making it secure requires a bit of experience, especially as you should make sure the encrypted fields are bound to their field name and the record so an attacker can't exchange values to a place somewhere where your apps decrypt it automatically. Typically for each entry and field an own generated key is used that is derived from a master key (-> key derivation).